# Popover control changes its location on select of different table view rows

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uipopovercontroller, popover

Iam working with two popover controllers for country and state selection respectively.The country and state details are placed in a table view.when i tap a country  row ,respective states popover gets displayed on another popover with given frame.This works fine for 4 rows data.But when the country data rows are more than 4,the state popover gets displayed in the other corner i.e changes its position .
here is the code for creating popover in didSelect row method

```
StateSelection_iPad *classCourse = [[StateSelection_iPad alloc] init];
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:classCourse];
    popover.delegate = self;
    classCourse.popNewDelegate=self;
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50,-40, 200, 300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
[classCourse release];
```

and in .m class

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 220);
```

How to get the popover on the given frame everytime i tap table row wih 'n' number of rows

Answer (score 0):

use this code for display the popoveron selected row

> UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
>
> NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [table2 indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
>
> int rows=clickedButtonPath.row;
>
> int section1=clickedButtonPath.section;
>
> ```
>      OR
> ```
>
> NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
>   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
>   CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
>
> [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(currentTouchPosition.x-10, clickedCell.frame.origin.y+100, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];

change the frame as per your requirement.